# Make Foreground a Backgrounded Job invoked by Start-Job in Powershell for Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, background, foreground

In Bash, it is possible to start a job in the background by putting an `&` at the end of the command. It is also possible to bring that job to the foreground by using the `fg` command, with appropriate job id if need be.

In Powershell, I understand the `&` equivalent is the `Start-Job` command. However, I am unable to find any information on methods to do the `fg` equivalent. Is there anyway to do that? Note that I am not asking about getting output. Rather, my question is as follows.

**Does there exist a way to bring a running job to the foreground, taking control of the Powershell Window?**

The main reason that such feature is needed is so that I can send keys/strings to the running job.

Using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: AFAIK you can only get status (running/completed ++) and the result (`Receive-Job`) with jobs started using `Start-Job`. The closest thing I could think of atm. would `xxx-PSSession` cmdlets. You could create multiple pssesions, invoke a script or command in a session, then enter the session after a while to ex. respond to a prompt. Never tried it, but PowerShell supports it. Not sure if you can create the sessions locally or if you would need a to use a remote computer as the "server".

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can do this with the `-Wait` switch of the `Receive-Job` command, e.g. `Receive-Job -Wait -Id 3` (where 3 is the Id returned by `Start-Job`)

Here's an example of how I tested this (in PowerShell 5, with the output included):

```
> Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Something"; Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Something Else"}

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Read-Host -Prompt "Ent...

> Receive-Job -Wait -Id 1
Enter Something: something!
something!
Enter Something Else: something else!
something else!
```

So after issuing the `Receive-Job -Wait` command, the job went to the foreground and I was able to enter `something!` and `something else!` in response to the two prompts from the script block I passed to `Start-Job`.

Answer (score 2):

I've been burning the midnight oil and banging my head up against Google search after Google search. It turns out this is pretty easy using [invoke-item](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-item.html).

Here is how I'm using it:

```
invoke-item .\form.ps1
timeout /t 90
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%form.ps1%'" Call Terminate
```

This will call my script `form.ps1` (a Windows form that I created) from within PowerShell. The Parent will continue to execute while `form.ps1` is running.

I'm using

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%form.ps1%'" Call Terminate
```

to kill the form by its command line name.